# Como faço para remover os milésimos de um valor?

Tags: lua

Por exemplo

```
number=10.123456
```

como faço para remover os milésimos de number para que fique apenas `10.12`?Me ajudem por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução possível é criar uma função para arredondamento, utilizando a função [math.floor](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-math.floor):

```
function arredonda(num, numCasasDecimais)
   local mult = 10^(numCasasDecimais or 0)
   return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end
```

Após a execução:

```
> a=10.123456
> arredonda(a, 2)
10.12
>
```

A função acima é apenas um exemplo. Para implementações mais eficientes e/ou precisas, consulte a referência (em inglês): [Simple Round](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleRound)

Answer (score 3):

Tente também `string.format("%.2f",number)`.